# MariaDB uses almost 100% CPU usage when innodb-encryption-threads > 1

Tags: encryption, mariadb

Our MariaDB server suddenly started to use all available CPU on our encrypted database. 
It doesn't seem to have an impact on performance though.

It seems to be a thread locking issues and setting innodb-encryption-threads from 4 to 1 fixes the issue.
Which correspond to 4 threads using all the cpu (50% each on a dual core).

An `strace` on one of the offending threads floods with this:

```
futex(0x561733657bc4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561733657b60, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561733657b60, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7fb4ede24af0, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1520416318, tv_nsec=32097000}, 0xffffffff) = 0
futex(0x7fb4ede24a90, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7fb4ede24a90, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
sched_yield()
```

What is causing this and how can we fix it?

Comment: Have you tried 2 threads?  That is, no more threads than CPU cores.

Comment: Yes, it does it with 2 threads as well.

Answer (score 0):

When saturating a server resource (CPU/IO/etc), and you have control over how many threads/processes/requests/etc are demanding the resource, it is often better to throttle the number of threads back.

In your example, you have 4 threads hitting 2 cores.  In doing so, each thread is taking twice (4/2) as long as it could to finish its task (encrypting something).

That is, 4 things (InnoDB blocks?) are being locked for twice as long.  Versus 2 things being locked for less time.

Comment: That makes sense. The issue here is that they are actually not really doing anything. They use all the CPU even if I run it on DB with no connection. It seems they are spending CPU waiting on each other if I understand the futex correctly.

Comment: File a bug with mariadb.com